Работает только стартовая команда бот телеграм
Прикрепляю код с самого начала, но код перестает работать со строчки 24. Команда /start работает, а на другие команды бот не реагирует. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так.
import time
import asyncio
import logging
import requests

import aiogram
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.filters.command import Command

#logging.basicConfig(level=logging.info)
bot = Bot(token="")

dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.message(Command("start"))
async def start_handler(message: types.Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    user_full_name = message.from_user.full_name
    logging.info(f'{user_id=} {user_full_name=} {time.asctime()}')
    await message.reply(f"Привет! Рад тебя видеть, {user_full_name}")

@dp.message(Command("hello"))
async def info(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Получить прогноз погоды', callback_data='city'))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Список команд', callback_data='list'))   
    await message.reply(f"Тут ты можешь узнать прогноз погоды", reply_markup=markup)

@dp.message(Command("listCity"))
async def reply(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('London'))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Moscow'))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Saint Petersburg'))
    await message.reply(reply_markup=markup)


async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

Терминал выдает следующее:
/usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/sofia/Desktop/dl_testovoe_bot/testovoe.py
ERROR:aiogram.event:Cause exception while process update id=284569412 by bot id=7159157542
ValidationError: 1 validation error for InlineKeyboardMarkup
inline_keyboard
Field required [type=missing, input_value={}, input_type=dict]
For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 309, in _process_update
response = await self.feed_update(bot, update, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 158, in feed_update
response = await self.update.wrap_outer_middleware(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/middlewares/error.py", line 25, in call
return await handler(event, data)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/middlewares/user_context.py", line 27, in call
return await handler(event, data)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/fsm/middleware.py", line 41, in call
return await handler(event, data)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/telegram.py", line 121, in trigger
return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/handler.py", line 43, in call
return await wrapped()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 276, in _listen_update
return await self.propagate_event(update_type=update_type, event=event, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/router.py", line 128, in propagate_event
return await observer.wrap_outer_middleware(_wrapped, event=event, data=kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/router.py", line 123, in _wrapped
return await self._propagate_event(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/router.py", line 148, in _propagate_event
response = await observer.trigger(event, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/telegram.py", line 121, in trigger
return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/handler.py", line 43, in call
return await wrapped()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/sofia/Desktop/dl_testovoe_bot/testovoe.py", line 24, in info
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 164, in init
pydantic_self.pydantic_validator.validate_python(data, self_instance=pydantic_self)
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for InlineKeyboardMarkup
inline_keyboard
Field required [type=missing, input_value={}, input_type=dict]
For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing

Уже видел сегодня от Вас вопрос, повторюсь: пожалуйста, ознакомитесь с документацией библиотеки aiogram, вопросов станет в разы меньше.
Прочитав документацию, Вы бы знали, что InlineKeyboardButton обязательно должен содержать callback_data,
 markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('London'))
markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Moscow'))
markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Saint Petersburg'))

Вероятно, тут Вы хотели использовать KeyboardButton, а не InlineKeyboardButton

Немного поправлю. Тут, скорее, не документацию к aiogram читать нужно, а документацию Bot API. У метода InlineKeyboardButton обязательный параметр только текст, остальные необязательные. Но, при использовании этого метода необходимо использовать один из необязательный параметров (You must use exactly one of the optional fields). Это может быть или callback_data или url и тд
